# How does iterative clip decide its processing order?

Tags: qgis, clip, algorithm

I have a fishnet grid which I use to iteratively clip several large shapefiles. The output of the clipping tool results in the selected output filename plus an incrementing suffix (_0, _1, _2 ... _n).

I have noticed while testing that the order of clipping is different every time. Once it goes from bottom left to top right, row by row. The next time it is completely random, and the other time it goes from top left to bottom right, column by column.

This has all been on QGIS 2.18, so how does it decide this order? The only factor is the size of the input fishnet grid, but I don't get how this affects the order of clipping.

Comment: I have found out it is not the order of clipping that happens in a certain order, it's in the creation of the fishnet grid.